# Firebase Admin: How can I get the previous page of Users from listUsers()?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

The Firebase Admin SDK function [**`Auth.listUsers`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#list-users) retrieves a list of users, and I have implemented a paging DataGrid in my app to display them.

My problem is that I have no way to control the offset for going back to a previous page. The example for [**List all users**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) shows how to use the `pageToken` in the returned [**`ListUsersResult`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.ListUsersResult.html) to move to the next batch of users. But there does not appear to be any way to go back to the previous page/batch of users.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a feature request to send to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cache the `pageTokens` and then select the desired token corresponding to the page.

```
let pageTokens = [];

function listUsers(page) {
  let nextPageToken = pageTokens[page];

  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function (listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function (userRecord) {
        console.log('user', userRecord.toJSON());
      });
      pageToken[page + 1] = listUsersResult.pageToken;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want to push the page tokens though, jumping back and forth between pages, the pageTokens grows without matching pageNumber correct. I am instead trying pageTokens[page] = listUsersResult.pageToken

Comment: @BrianOgden Good point; see update. Feel free to edit the answer.